# PHP-function for querying out of the database

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I want to have a simple admin-script which allows me to disable or enable different modules of the website, e.g. changelogs or news.

For this I have created a datase table which looks like:

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| id | function     | enabled |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  | changelogs   | on      |
| 2  | news         | off     |
| .. | ..           | ..      |'
+----+--------------+---------+
```

As I said, I want to get the information whether a module is on or off with a php-function.
I did this but it didn't work for me.

**functions.php:**

```
$db = new mysqli("is correct", "is correct", "is correct", "is correct");

function function_enabled($function_module) {
    if ($function_module == "changelogs") {
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT enabled FROM functions WHERE function = '$function_module'");
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) {
            $return = $row->enabled;
        }
        return "$return";
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
include("functions.php");
if(function_enabled("changelogs") == "on") {
    echo'Result or menu here...';
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Add more details on "didn't work". Print some variable states in between. And why isn't the `enabled` column just a boolean?

Comment: Put braces around $function_module, and if you're not using the $db elsewhere, put it in the function body.

Comment: Also, don't wrap your return value in quotes.

Comment: I try to stray away from using words like "function" as a column name in MySQL. It's possible that you are using a reserved word and the query isn't being executed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$db` doesn't exist within your `function_enabled` function because of [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You need to pass it to that function, run your `new mysqli` within the function, make `$db` a global variable or singleton, or otherwise make it accessible within the function.

Comment: Worked! I had to connect to the database within the function and not at the beginning of functions.php